# Positive definiteness of the function

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Given is the following function

$f(x)=q y+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} y^2+g x}$

with

$q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1-\gamma}{1+\gamma}$

where $x\geq 0$, $y\leq 0$,$g > 0$ and $\gamma \in[0,1)$. Show that this function is positive definite.

I am not sure how to do it. I thought about writing

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} y^2+g x} > -q y$ and squaring, but not sure how to deal with then

$\frac{1}{2} y^2+g x > (q y)^2$

Comment: Just edited @TurlocTheRed

Answer (score 1):

$\gamma = \cos \theta, 0\le \theta < \pi/2.$

$q=(1/\sqrt{2})\frac{(1-\cos \theta)}{1+\cos\theta}=(1/\sqrt{2}) \tan^2 \theta /2$

$q^2y^2<y^2/2+gx$

$(q^2-1/2)y^2<gx$

Here's a jump.

$q^2<1/2$

$(1/2) \tan^4 (\theta /2)<1/2$

$\tan^4(\theta/2)<1$

---

$0\le \theta < \pi/2 \implies 0 \le \tan^4 (\theta/2)<1\implies (q^2-1/2)<0$

$\implies (q^2-1/2)y^2<gx\implies -qy<\sqrt{y^2/2+gx}\implies 0<qy+\sqrt{y^2/2+gx}$

I think that does it.